# How to get video src using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a downloadable video links in a website. For example, I am working with urls like these `https://www.loc.gov/item/2015669100/`. You can see that there is a m3u8 video link under `mejs__mediaelement` div tag.

However my code is not printing anything. Meaning that it's not finding the Video urls for the website.

My code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

with open('pages2crawl.txt', 'r') as inFile:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in inFile]

for page in lines:
        req = Request(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read(), 'html.parser')
        pages = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'mejs__mediaelement'})
        for e in pages:
                video = e.find("video").get("src")
                if video.endswith("m3u8"):
                        print(video)
```

Comment: Your problem is, that your serached div tag will not delivered (to me). I can see a m3u8 file, but none of there parents are a div with this given class (In the browser i see this div). Maybe you get other data than your browser because of the user agent. You have to look the answers to find another way to locate, or try to get the same data as your browser

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a simple script it would probably be easier to use regex.

```
import re, requests

s = requests.Session() #start the session
data = s.get(url) #http get request to download data
data = data.text #get the raw text

vidlinks = re.findall("src='(.*?).m3u8'/>", data) #find all between the two parts in the data
print(vidlinks[0] + ".m3u8") #print the full link with extension
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `source[type="application/x-mpegURL"]` to extract MPEG link (or `source[type="video/mp4"]` to extract mp4 link):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.loc.gov/item/2015669100/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

link_mpeg = soup.select_one('source[type="application/x-mpegURL"]')["src"]
link_mp4 = soup.select_one('source[type="video/mp4"]')["src"]
print(link_mpeg)
print(link_mp4)
```

Prints:

```
https://tile.loc.gov/streaming-services/iiif/service:afc:afc2010039:afc2010039_crhp0001:afc2010039_crhp0001_mv04/full/full/0/full/default.m3u8
https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/afc/afc2010039/afc2010039_crhp0001/afc2010039_crhp0001_mv04.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, I like your answer, I tried to find out the source of the video in webpage "https://www1.wdr.de/fernsehen/lokalzeit/ostwestfalen/videos/video-lokalzeit-owl---1304.html" but I got the error ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``` any idea why?